# Which pipeline is this, found outside the launch vehicle?

Tags: identify-this-object, launch-vehicle, electron

which pipeline is this found on the electron launch vehicle?
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a raceway which houses wiring and plumbing for the systems since you can't run them through the tanks as the walls are so thin, the Falcon 9 has this as well. [image: Falcon 9's Raceway]

Comment: Clarifying info: Those rockets do not have an exterior cover, and then propellant tanks inside them. The exterior wall of the rocket *is* the wall of the propellant tanks. As those tanks are thin-walled, and cryogenic, it is much easier to runt he needed data cables (and sometimes soem plumbing too) along the outside. Being outside and exposed to environment and wind, they are covered by the protective and reasonably aerodynamic raceway cover.

Comment: p.s. sorry about the spelling in that previous comment. Typing before my first coffee brings my dyslexia to the fore.